# Problem withlimits on Line Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Problem:

> Evaluate the line integral of the vector  field  $$f(x,y)=(x^2-2xy)i+(y^2-2xy)j$$ from $(-1,1)$ to $(1,1)$ along the parabola $y=x^2$.

I can't understand how to set limits on the Line Integral. While I identified $f(x,y)$ as the vector field defined and bounded on the graph of $\alpha$, I can't understand how to get $\alpha$ (the piecewise smooth path in n-space defined on the interval $[a,b]$-as it says in my textbook), nor how to work out $f.d\alpha$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, if you have a line parametrised as $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb R^n$ and a vector field $f: \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, then the interval of the vector field along the line is defined as

$$\int f d\gamma = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) dt$$

In your case:

$$f(x,y) = (x^2 - 2xy, y^2-2xy)\\
\gamma(t) = (t, t^2) \text{ on } [-1,1]$$

Now, just plug in the numbers and see what comes out.

Comment: @BetterWorld The parabola $y=x^2$ is actually a graph of the function $f(x)=x^2$, do you agree?

Comment: @BetterWorld Please don't call me sir, we are all friends here. And you are almost correct, in fact, $\alpha_1(t)=t$ and $\alpha_2(t) = t^2$ (since, in that case, $y=\alpha_2(t)=t^2=\alpha_1(t)^2=x^2$, which is what the original demand is. Now, you need to plug that into the definition of the line integral...

Comment: @BetterWorld What I meant is that $t$ is a parameter that goes from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: @BetterWorld Do you know about line parametrization?

Comment: @BetterWorld Any book that teaches line integrals has a chapter (before integrals) about line parametrisation.

Comment: @BetterWorld i'm sorry to say this, but if you do not understand the concept of a parametrization of a line, you should not be learning line integrals yet. I don't mean to be disrespectful, but you need to first study up the basics.

Comment: @BetterWorld I learnt that in my native language, so I cannot help you there, sorry.